# Swift create and center ImageViews programmatically

Tags: swift, layout, imageview, constraints

I have an array of images (icons) and i want to create and place them horizontally centered by X.

Here is an example:

```
    for uniquePlatform in uniquePlatforms {
        if uniquePlatform == "Platform1" {
            let platformImage = UIImage(named: "icPlatform1")
            let platformImageView = PlatformImageView(image: platformImage)
            platformImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.addSubview(platformImageView)
            platformImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 11).isActive = true
            platformImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor, constant: CGFloat(???)).isActive = true
            platformImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: platformImage!.size.width).isActive = true
            platformImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: platformImage!.size.height).isActive = true
        }
        if uniquePlatform == "Platform2" {
            let platformImage = UIImage(named: "icPlatform2")
            let platformImageView = PlatformImageView(image: platformImage)
            platformImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.addSubview(platformImageView)
            platformImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 11).isActive = true
            platformImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor, constant: CGFloat(???)).isActive = true
            platformImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: platformImage!.size.width).isActive = true
            platformImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: platformImage!.size.height).isActive = true
        }
```

What i want: if platforms count == 1, just one icon that will be centered. If > 1, they all should be centered and space betweend them should be 12. Each icon also has different width/height[image]

Comment: Consider adding your image views to an encapsulating stack view (`UIStackView`), that should provide the behaviour that you desire.

Comment: It's exactly what i want. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear that a stack view worked for you!